# Google Oauth2 in GWT and AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement authentication for Google Drive:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/drive/auth/web-server

1st, it's not obvious when the user is redirected to the Google login page to authenticate. It doesn't appear they are showing that part.

2nd, it doesn't show the call back code. I think I can figure that out and will need to add a new servlet or service or EntryPoint, but might be tricky with GWT.

3rd, and most important, I keep getting a ClassNotFoundException even though the class exists and it compiles fine.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestInitializer
    at com.onix.sdm.server.SDMServiceImpl.loginServer(SDMServiceImpl.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:215)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 47 more
```

It is dying on this line:

```
37      DriveAuthentication da = new DriveAuthentication(); // Same as MyClass
```

So how do you add Google Oauth2 into GWT?

Answer (score 2):

GWT is a client technology, but the link you posted is for server auth. So the first step is to decide which method you want to use.

If you want server auth, then the link you posted is correct and GWT will know nothing about it. Your GWT app will call you server using RPC/REST etc, and your server will do the Drive access.

On the other hand, if you want to do client auth, then you'll need this link https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent which describes the URLs you need to post to. My recommendation is to stay away from the libraries, and understand and send the raw URLs yourself.

Comment: Either client or server is fine. If client, I would submit the refresh and access token to the server. It would not compile in .client package. It said InputStream class not found (or similar). This IS in .server package, and it won't run! Seems more a problem of AppEngine than GWT. Would love to use raw URLs. Have implemented Oauth2 before in Perl using that, but was very tricky. Why re-invent wheel if they provide a SDK? Problem is they change the abstraction for every SDK library.

Comment: May I humbly suggest you haven't quite grasped client v. server auth. In client auth,there is NO refresh token. You kinda answered your own question at the end. imho the oauth SDK is a very leaky abstraction. I abandoned it after several frustrating weeks. To DIY it's only 3 urls. (1) a redirect URL to authorise/identify which then redirects to your callback servlet with an authorization code; (2) a POST URL to convert an access code to a refresh token (which you store); (3) a POST URL to request an accesstoken using a refreshtoken. Everything you need to know is on 1 page http://goo.gl/1CoFpk

Comment: You misunderstood. *.client and *.server are the packages GWT places client and server code respectively. Either location for the OAuth code is fine with me.

Comment: I know GWT. My point is that the code is different (very, very different) depending on whether you want to do server Oauth or client Oauth. The Oauth flows are totally different, with different implications on your app and the user experience. You need to understand the two flows and then decide which one is appropriate for your needs.

Comment: Need the server Oauth. Need refresh tokens & access tokens. Need to run if user not logged in or logs out. Oauth authentication can be GWT client side or GWT server side. Currently working on GWT server side Oauth authentication. Tricky letting client side know user is authenticated after /oauth2callback.

Comment: The approach I took is that I only serve my application page to an authenticated user. If the server decides the user is not authenticated (ie. no valid stored refreshtoken), then I serve a signup page.