# What is the difference between Program Files\Eclipse\plugins, ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.*/plugins, and ~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

What are the following directories used for?

- Program Files\Eclipse\plugins
- ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_2049681907/plugins/
- ~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins

My Eclipse is SO flaky. I have to frequently delete these directories and re-install everything.

Comment: Whats the difference between that and ......?

Comment: Be more specific about flaky.  What kind of behavior are you seeing?  What errors in your error logs? What extra plugins do you have installed?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg Examples of flaky: [_One_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168082/eclipse-appengine-java-lang-runtimeexception-cannot-get-the-system-java-compi), [_Two_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143727/google-oauth2-in-gwt-and-appengine).

Answer (score 0):

- `Program Files\Eclipse\plugins`

  Is used for the original plugins that come with eclipse, and plugins from the sdk's and other stuff you download.
- `~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_2049681907/plugins/`

  This one I'm not sure, but I think it's about the updates.
- `~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins`

  This one is about the preffered for your projects, and it's hidden.

Comment: The .eclipse folder is used when the actual eclipse installation is not writable by the current user (AKA a shared installation).  The user can still install plugins, but they will be placed in the .eclipse folder.