# Eclipse, AppEngine: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-eclipse-plugin

I'm getting this error when trying to deploy to Google AppEngine. I DO have JDK selected!

```
------------ Deploying frontend ------------

Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\Chloe\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8759974391667459604.tmp'
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Compiling jsp files.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.

Debugging information may be found in C:\Users\Chloe\AppData\Local\Temp\appengine-deploy6465203991005024943.log
```

C:\Users\Chloe\AppData\Local\Temp\appengine-deploy6465203991005024943.log:

```
Unable to update:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJavaFiles(Application.java:814)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJsps(Application.java:801)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:615)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:55)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:433)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

I've cleaned the project, re-installed Eclipse to latest version, re-installed all plugins, etc. I've also edited Program Files\Java\eclipse-kepler-4.3\eclipse.ini with

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\javaw.exe
```

at the top and before -vmargs.

Comment: Instead of project/facets, check project/Build Path for the JDK

Comment: Go to command prompt & type path check that whether it's JDK or JRE

Comment: That is already mentioned in the question. Whatever it was, is not happening any more and I don't remember how it resolved itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938995/google-app-engine-jsp-cant-deploy-java-lang-runtimeexception-cannot-get-the-s

Answer (score 7):

Go to Eclipse folder where you have eclipse installed (say c:\eclipse). You will find eclipse.ini file which eclipse uses to while starting. 
Add the following line
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javaw.exe

change the above java path with your location of JDK. It should be able to use this JDK and will compile and deploy to app engine.

Comment: That is already mentioned in the question. Whatever it was, is not happening any more and I don't remember how it resolved itself.

Comment: I was having the same issue like you. However when I put the correct JDK path in eclipse.ini and restarted my eclipse as well as my PC it started working. I even tried this in another laptop and I noticed the same. Sometime if you add JDK in eclipse 'Installed JRE' it doesn't want to recognize until you setup this in eclipse.ini and restart your eclipse. So this is the answer if anyone is still struggling with the same issue.

Comment: worked for me :) thanks (had jdk in installed jre and not .ini file )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938995/google-app-engine-jsp-cant-deploy-java-lang-runtimeexception-cannot-get-the-s

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying to `File>Restart` the Eclipse but not working when exited and run again It works

Comment: Right...everything done right, Eclipse needs to be closed and started again, and not a restart. Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**WOW!!!** I was dealing with this issue for like 3-4 hours. Was just about to comment saying fuck this. But then I changed the eclipse.ini to:

```
-vm
A:/Programming/Java/jdk1.8.0_73/bin/javaw.exe
```

instead of:

```
-vm
A:/Programming/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/javaw.exe
```

**AND SUCCESS!**

Why this might have worked? Not really sure. I needed 1.7 not 1.8... but 1.7 kept pointing to a JRE instead of the JDK... And surprisingly 1.8 didn't do that + still worked with the current build. Also worth mentioning to specify 1.7 in facets /build path & compiler..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see that the OP is using Google Plugin for Eclipse (GPE), which is deprecated, but this was once also a problem in Cloud Tools for Eclipse (CT4E), so I'll leave a relevant answer for CT4E here for reference.

It was indeed a bug of Cloud Tools for Eclipse that it did not use the JDK configured for a project but instead used the JDK used to launch Eclipse for staging. The bug has been fixed: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/2195.

So, others answers in this question to edit `eclipse.ini` to change the JDK to launch Eclipse are a temporary workaround that is no longer needed. Just update to the latest CT4E version and set a JDK for a project. You can specify whatever JDK/JRE necessary in `eclipse.ini` for launching Eclipse.